# Inserting noncrossing partions

Tags: macros, symbols

I am trying to create non crossing partions in latex. That is to connect numbers with lines drawn below them. An example would be

1 2 3 4  5

│└┘││

└───┘

But the lines should be directly underneath the numbers and there does not need to be gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using a multipart rectangles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
myshape/.style={
  rectangle split,
  rectangle split parts=#1,
  anchor=center,
  rectangle split horizontal}
}
\newcommand\drawline[4]{%
  \draw ([xshift=2pt]#1.#2) |- +(0,-#4) -| ([xshift=2pt]#1.#3);}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[myshape=5] (rec)
{1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4\nodepart{five}5};
\drawline{rec}{text}{five}{20pt}
\drawline{rec}{two}{four}{10pt}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\node[myshape=6] (rec)
{1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4\nodepart{five}5\nodepart{six}6};
\end{scope}
\drawline{rec}{text}{six}{20pt}
\drawline{rec}{two}{three}{10pt}
\drawline{rec}{four}{five}{10pt}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]